# oracle sql query error while comparing date columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following oracle sql query in which START_DATE is a number column and a_date is DATE type and the input value is also of type DATE. kindly let me know how to compare the date columns with the input date.

```
select a.id ,a.v ,b.id,b.v  
 from DATA a ,FDC  b  where a.START_DATE = to_date('11-DEC-10','YYYYMMDD')
 and a.START_DATE = b.a_date and b.code = 'JFK'
```

Comment: The obvious question here is "how do you store a date in a number column"? You need to explain what format the number has, so we can tell you how to convert it to a date...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.id ,a.v ,b.id,b.v  
 from DATA a ,FDC  b  where a.START_DATE LIKE TO_DATE('11-DEC-10','DD-MON-YY')
 and a.START_DATE = b.a_date and b.code = 'JFK'
```

If you stored your START_DATE as Number like `'YYYYMMDD'`:

```
a.START_DATE=TO_NUMBER(TO_DATE('20101211','YYYYMMDD'))
```

Comment: @Mohamed a.START_DATE is number type and b.a_date is date type.

Comment: how it number is stored? DDMMYYY ?

Comment: @Mohamed they have stored as number for START_DATE.

Comment: @Suresh: Mohamed is trying to find out what the "number value" for e.g. "December 14th, 2010" is in your column?

Comment: @Mohamed the value as number is in the following way 20101112 it means 12-NOV-2010.

Comment: @Suresh I hope the above answer is fine, if not please update me

Comment: @Mohamad your answer is slightly correct,as i have to convert START_DATE to to_char and convert to date using to_date.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what format your number start_date column is stored in.

However, it would probably be easier if you used the predicate on the true date column, and joined using a format mask just once.

For example:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.v, 
       b.id,
       b.v  
  FROM data a, 
       fdc b
 WHERE b.a_date = to_date('11-DEC-2010','DD-MON-RRRR')
   AND a.start_date = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(b.a_date, 'DDMMRRRR'))
   AND b.code = 'JFK'
```

Please note that the date format matches the format of the date you are comparing - `b.a_date = to_date('11-DEC-2010','DD-MON-RRRR')`. This query assumes that the a.start_date column is stored in the format `DDMMRRRR`. You would need to amend this for whichever format your date is stored in e.g. a.start_date = `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(b.a_date, 'J'))` for a Julian date.

P.s. Why use a number to store a date?

Answer (score -1):

select * from tbltlcrconfighistory where TO_DATE(STARTDATE,'dd-mon-yyyy') = TO_DATE('14-dec-2010','dd-mon-yyyy');

Comment: You can not convert an number simply like TO_DATE(STARTDATE,'dd-mon-yyyy'). In the StartDate may not have '-' hyphen inside the texts.

Answer (score -1):

select * from tbltlcrconfighistory where STARTDATE = TO_DATE('14-dec-2010','dd-mon-yyyy');